# Difficulty in Implementing a simple single-layer RNN using Pytorch's base class “nn.Linear” class

Tags: python, pytorch, typeerror, recurrent-neural-network

While working on making a simple RNN using Pytorch nn.linear function. So firstly I initialized my weights as

```
self.W_x = nn.Linear(self.input_dim, self.hidden_dim, bias=True)
self.W_h = nn.Linear(self.hidden_dim, self.hidden_dim, bias=True)
```

Now in the main step where I am getting the result of the current state by using the previous state and the values of the weights using this code statement

```
h_t = np.tanh((inp * self.W_x) + (prev_h * self.W_h))
```

So here I am getting the python error as shown below

```
TypeError: mul(): argument 'other' (position 1) must be Tensor, not Linear
```

Can anyone help me with his regards...

Comment: what is single layer RNNN

Comment: @prosti single layer RNN means a single layer of neurons in which every output of 1st neuron is the input for the second and the sequence continues.

Answer (score 1):

Your `W_x` and `W_h` are not weights, but linear layers, which use a weight and bias (since `bias=True`). They need to be called as a function.

Furthermore, you cannot use NumPy operations with PyTorch tensors, but if you convert your tensors to NumPy arrays you can't back propagate through them, since only PyTorch operations are tracked in the computational graph. There is no need for `np.tanh` anyway, as PyTorch has [`torch.tanh`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.tanh) as well.

```py
h_t = torch.tanh(self.W_x(inp) + self.W_h(prev_h))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out the mistake. Hopefully, it would help me to solve my problems. Have a good day Michael.